# How to convert Z3Py code to C# code (Z3, SAT)

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

in past i write some Z3Py code that i want now convert to C# .NetCore. I check many examples but i have some problems :-)

I have defined function with name MyFun, that accept parameter and return variable based on value. Simple example:

```
H0 = BitVec('H0', 8)
H1 = BitVec('H1', 8)
H2 = BitVec('H2', 8)
H3 = BitVec('H3', 8)
I1 = BitVec('I1', 8)
T1 = BitVec('T1', 8)

def MyFun(N):
  return z3.If(N == 0x00, H0,
         z3.If(N == 0x01, H1,
         z3.If(N == 0x02, H2, H3)))

s.add(T1 == z3.If(MyFun(I1) == 0x33, 0x11, 0x12) )
```

I have problem with "*function definition*" and also problem with "*z3.If*". I think *MkFuncDecl* is for something else. Maybe solution is create normal **C# Function** with classic **C# If** and then directly call it? I think it must be somehow defined inside Z3... (due speed, Z3 <-> C#) Or maybe it was working also with the same way inside Z3Py (**Python function** with, **Python If** wrapper)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a regular C# function, but calling Z3's `If`, not C#'s `If`. Essentially you're building the abstract-syntax-tree for the expression, it just happens to be in C# as opposed to Python. Otherwise, it's the same.

Comment: Hmmm, but what command is for **Z3's If** in **C#** :-) I search for all IF's but nothing useful found (Context.MkIff, Context.When, Context.Then...)

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#a25d82707ade078db9685a6f921838b4d

Comment: Yes, This is correct answer. Equivalent Z3Py `z3.If` function in C# is `MkITE (BoolExpr t1, Expr t2, Expr t3)`. Thank you very much ;-)